# React installation

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, npm-install

I am installing React at my local environment, 
when i am running bellow command:

"npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev"

I am getting lots of errors see below:

```
E:\xamp\htdocs\Reactjs>npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "webpack" "webpack-dev-server" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10

npm ERR! Invalid protocol: null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! E:\xamp\htdocs\Reactjs\npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Start by looking in the log file as the helpful error message suggests. `npm ERR! Invalid protocol: null` is suspicious.

Comment: You might kill your brain using windows OS :p To have a smooth dev experience switch to Linux or MAC.

Comment: FYI: I develop with react/npm/yarn/etc on windows without issue, but I use the Git bash command line prompt in windows.

Comment: does other npm installs work correctly? are you behind proxy?

Comment: @meta4 yes npm is installed correctly , it is version 3.10.10

Comment: Try using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), it does all the configuration for you in just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12939 - this npm issue can be related to your problem.

First, you need to check if your environment variable is set - execute "set http" in Windows command prompt. If there's anything other than "Environment variable is not defined", try to execute "set http_proxy=" command. It will temporarily remove the http_proxy variable.

If this helps, next step will be to remove it from System Properties > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables.